# How to take updates from branch in azure devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-bash

I have clone the angular project folder from azure devops and tried to get if any new updates in that folder. I have tried below the commands but not working. If anyone know the command please help to find the solution.

git clone https://dev.azure.com/testproject/_git/angularproject

cd angularproject

git branch release/main

git checkout release/main

git pull origin release/main

Comment: What's the default branch name of `https://dev.azure.com/testproject/_git/angularproject`? It could be `master` or `main`. Try `git pull origin main` instead of `git pull origin release/main`.

Comment: @ElpieKay: release/main is a branch